# How to manually import extension functions when using Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha11?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I have a `List<Item>` that I want to be displayed using Jetpack Compose. In version "1.0.0-alpha10", this code:

```
@Composable
fun ItemsScreen(items: List<Item>) {
    item?.let {
        LazyColumn {
            items(
                    items = items
            ) { item ->
                ItemCard(item = item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine, but, starting with "1.0.0-alpha11", according to the new [updates](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.0.0-alpha11):

> New items(count: Int) factory method for scope of LazyColumn/LazyRow/LazyVerticalGrid. items(items: List) and itemsIndexed(items: List) are now extension functions so you have to manually import them when used.

My app doesn't work any more. I'm not sure I understand:

> items(items: List) are now extension functions so you have to manually import.

What does it mean? How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add this import for the extension function [`LazyListScope.items()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#items):

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```